# Why does my mesh keep breaking when I scale a curve?

Tags: rigging

I wanted to make a tank track, for robot model, for my video game in Unity, I created a single chain, made an array of it, set the curve modifier and i have a problem with rigging, I thought I did it in right way, but this is my first time doing something like this. Everything looked fine at first glance, I parented a armature with chain, with automatic weights and still everything looked fine. But when I wanted to modify my curve, my chain mesh breaks. How can i fix that?
I followed an youtube tutorial, and I think, I did that exactly the same way as that guy from tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8qZN3cjX4c&t=629s

Here is some pictures:
[image: Everything is fine here]

[image: But here breaks after resizing a curve]

If you have a better way to solve my problem, let me know because I am totally inexperienced in blender.

My .blend file:

[image]

Comment: tbh...i just watched a minute or so to the video - but if you are a total beginner in Blender - you shouldn't do that now. You just get frustrated. Start with easy simple projects to gain experience. Watch tutorials WITH(!) voice explanation so you that you really learn something than just repeating what the tutorial does without knowing what you are doing. So i am sorry, but that's my honest opinion. And even for me - with now over 1 year experience - it would be hard to follow.

Comment: i recommend watching e.g. Polyfjords tutorials on yt which are brilliant, he explains great and easy to follow. Other free tutorials on yt are great too...like Grand Abbit or 1 minute blender...and lots of other guys

Comment: Ok, I haven't watched the tutorial yet, just had a sneak peek at your blend file. Do you really need 10 armatures?

Comment: @Blunder I don't really need 10 armatures, but dont know how to do that in another way ;c